# Wondering if async/await Solution is clean

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I came to the following code in one of my base classes which works perfectly (see the comment):

```
private static Dictionary<string, TItem> _cache;

protected Dictionary<string, TItem> Cache
{
    get
    {
        if (_cache == null)
        {
            // Instead of FillCacheAsync().Wait(); I now do the following:
            var reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            Task.Run(
                async () =>
                {
                    await FillCacheAsync();
                    reset.Set();
                });
            reset.WaitOne();
        }
        return _cache;
    }
}

private async Task FillCacheAsync()
{            
    _cache = new Dictionary<string, TItem>();
     await InternalCacheFillAsync();            
}

// This is not part of the question.
protected abstract Task InternalCacheFillAsync();
```

Is this a good solution for the problem that a lazy property can't be marked as `async`? I had huge problems here even with usage of `ConfigureAwait(false)` in place.

Comment: Why not use simple `FillCacheAsync().Wait()`? What is benefit of this extra work with event.

Comment: @Honza: As I wrote in my post this lead to heavy problems even if I carefully used `ConfigureAwait` all the way down.

Comment: The `AutoResetEvent` isn't really necessary; a better blocking solution would be `Task.Run(() => FillCacheAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. It would be *best* not to block at all, though - e.g., [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stephen Cleary covers this exact topic of [async properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) in his blog.

 
 
He suggests a clean way to answer your need to a cached value property that will be cached in an async way using [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20(NET45,%20Win8,%20WP8,%20WPA81)/AsyncLazy.cs) from his [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx), it will save you the need to use AutoResetEvent and will simplify your code.

A simple example of your class with a cached property:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    static SomeClass()
    { 
        Cache = new AsyncLazy<Dictionary<string, TItem>>(GetCacheAsync);
    }

    public static AsyncLazy<Dictionary<string, TItem>> Cache { get; }

    private static Task<Dictionary<string, TItem>> GetCacheAsync()
    {
        ....
    }
}.
```

And the access to the value of the cached property:

```
Dictionary<string, TItem> value = await SomeClass.Cache;
```

Comment: Good stuff! So I guess, my solution isn't that suffisticated but still valid. I'll use Stephens lib anyways. He seems to know a lot more about the things than me :-).

Comment: I can't recommend more about his blog, every article there is a piece of gold. His book should be good either, though I haven't got time to read it yet.

Comment: Just a side note: use the newer [`AsyncEx.Coordination` library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination) if you can. The older `AsyncEx` library will be switching to the new version soon.